# getting both multiple results sets and output in Go, but how to scan output first?

Tags: sql-server, go

I'm executing a stored procedure (using go-mssqldb driver), and I'm getting multiple sets with results and then selecting the output. This is the snippet:

```
query := "DECLARE @ErrorMessage nvarchar(4000);"+
    "EXEC [Schema].[Action] "+
    "@myInputParam=?,"+
    "@ErrorMessage = @ErrorMessage OUTPUT;"+
    "SELECT ErrorMessage = @ErrorMessage;"

ctx: ...

rows, err := r.DB.QueryxContext(ctx, query, "blabla")
```

in this way I can read and scan the results sets in the rows with the combination of `rows.Next()`and `rows.NextResultSet()`.

And in the end I `Scan` the ErrorMessage in last set.

BUT it happens that the stored may return only the ErrorMessage set, breaking my expectations in the code.

So what I need is to always read the output first and then, if no error, proceed with the waltz of the reads and scans of the other sets.

I tried this way hoping to populate the var errorMessage:

```
QueryxContext(ctx, query, "blabla", sql.Named("ErrorMessage", sql.Out{Dest: &errorMessage}))
```

but it doesn't work and it complains with `sql: statement expects 1 inputs; got 2`

**EDIT1**

this is the stored I'm calling

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Schema].[Action]
    @myInputParam   VARCHAR(100),
    @ErrorMessage nvarchar(4000) OUTPUT
AS 
  BEGIN
      SELECT @Id = Id
      FROM ...
      WHERE Param = @myInputParam

      IF @Id IS NULL
        BEGIN
          SET @ErrorMessage = "some error";
        END
  END
GO
```

Comment: Could you provide more data, like a whole function or something? Is that the whole error message, is some file line mentioned? Is there a reason you've provided so little code?

Comment: yep sorry, I've added a snippet of the stored I'm using. About the rest of the code is normal code to handle the results and is working without problems. I only don't know how to read the OUTPUT first. I'm reading here it might be a known problem, https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/issues/369